# How do I fix unexpected redirection of visitors after enabling multisite on WP3?

Tags: customization, 404-error

After enabling SuperAdmin and multisite functionality in WP3 many users are getting redirected to a sign-up url.  I do not have account sign-up enabled, how do I turn this off?  It seems to happen when any invalid subdomain is used including my-domain.com instead of www.my-domain.com.

How do I fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my own question so others can find it in the future.

defining `NOBLOGREDIRECT` in `wp-config.php` to point to the url of your choice will correct this problem.

Sample:

```
define('NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://www.my-domain.com');
```